# MultichoiceModeListener on RecyclerView android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, contextmenu, long-press

I have a recyclerview with respective adapter. I want to show multiple customview menu options in toolbar on the long press of recyclerview item.
Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm doing the same work. This post is helpful: [RecyclerView with choice modes](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/recyclerview-part-2-choice-modes/)

Basically you have to add this code in your OnLongClick method

```
 @Override
public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
    if (!mMultiSelector.isSelectable()) {
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).startSupportActionMode(mActionModeCallback); // (2)
        mMultiSelector.setSelectable(true);
        mMultiSelector.setSelected(MyViewHolder.this, true);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Hope it helps